# ConnectionKit framework in xcode doesn't work with me

Tags: cocoa, xcode, frameworks, ftp

I've tried to make a Cocoa application that connects to ftp server.
All answers do suggest using connection Kit framework but somehow Im not able to use it.
As I compile the framework and add it to my xcode project and build it. Im not able to run the application anymore. I got error in left down corner saying that app exited with status 5.

After solving this one, now I get 9 errors when trying to build: (Heres copy paste)

```
AppDelegate.m:17: error: 'AbstractConnection' undeclared (first use in this function)
AppDelegate.m:50: error: syntax error before 'AbstractConnection'
AppDelegate.m:55: error: 'baseDirField' undeclared here (not in a function)
AppDelegate.m:56: error: syntax error before 'if'
AppDelegate.m:62: error: syntax error before 'AbstractConnection'
AppDelegate.m:69: error: syntax error before '}' token
AppDelegate.m:71: error: syntax error before 'AbstractConnection'
AppDelegate.m:75: error: syntax error before 'for'
AppDelegate.m:75: error: syntax error before '<' token
```

when trying to use following code (found with google):

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import < Cocoa/Cocoa.h >

@protocol AbstractConnectionProtocol;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
 IBOutlet NSTextField *hostNameField;
 IBOutlet NSTextField *usernameField;
 IBOutlet NSTextField *passwordField;
 IBOutlet NSTextField *baseDirField;
 IBOutlet NSTextView *log;
 IBOutlet NSTextField *status;

 id <AbstractConnectionProtocol> con;

 BOOL isConnected;
}

- (IBAction) connect:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) disConnect:(id)sender;

@end

//  AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import < Connection/Connection.h >

@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction) connect:(id)sender;
{
 NSError *err = nil;
 con = [[AbstractConnection connectionToHost:[hostNameField stringValue]
          port:@"21"
          username:[usernameField stringValue]
          password:[passwordField stringValue]
          error:&err] retain]; 
 if (!con)
 {
  if (err)
  {
   [NSApp presentError:err];
  }
  return;
 }

 NSTextStorage *textStorage = [log textStorage];
 [textStorage setDelegate:self];  // get notified when text changes
 [con setTranscript:textStorage]; 

 [con setDelegate:self];

 [status setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connecting to: %@", [hostNameField stringValue]]];
 [con connect];

}

- (IBAction) disConnect:(id)sender;
{
 if( con )
 {
  [con disconnect];
 }

}
- (void)connection:(AbstractConnection *)aConn didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host
{
 isConnected = YES;
 [status setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connected to: %@", host]];

 NSString *dir = [[baseDirField stringValue] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
 if (dir && [dir length] > 0)
  [con changeToDirectory:[baseDirField stringValue]];
 [con directoryContents];

}

- (void)connection:(AbstractConnection *)aConn didDisconnectFromHost:(NSString *)host
{
 isConnected = NO;
 [status setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Disconnected from: %@", host]];

 [con release];
 con = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(AbstractConnection *)aConn didReceiveContents:(NSArray *)contents ofDirectory:(NSString *)dirPath
{
 NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), dirPath);
 int i = 0;
 for (i=0; i < [contents count]; ++i) {
  id object = [contents objectAtIndex:i];
  [[[log textStorage] mutableString] appendFormat:@"%@\n", object];
 }
}

@end
```

So I would like to know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, is me again. I found the address of the site I downloaded the sample code because it seems that it messed up in the question. Its:

http://www.matthew-long.com/2007/11/24/cocoaobjective-c-ftp-libraryframework/

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #import < Connection/Connection.h >
> ```

Try removing those spaces. It's unlikely that you have a framework named “ Connection” with a header file named “Connection.h ” in it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `<Connection/Connection.h>` is importing everything you need (specifically the file that defines `AbstractConnection`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version you use, but at least in 1.2.2 connections conform to the protocol `CKAbstractConnection`, not `AbstractConnectionProtocol`. I think the code you found with Google is not for any current version of Connection Kit.

BTW, for me the 1.2 branch currently seems to work the best. And yes, the lack of sample code  that compiles and documentation can be quite frustrating whilst working with this framework.